# Website being flagged by Virgin Media's "Web Safe" security feature

Tags: wordpress, security, antivirus, websecurity

I operate a private (login required) Wordpress site for a client who recently had an employee move to the UK.

Their ISP there, Virgin Media, is blocking the website. I realize the employee could simply edit their Virgin Media user settings as suggested in the screenshot below, but is there anything I can do as the administrator/developer to whitelist the site?

Edit: I should add that i've done the preliminary check on google and looked for documentation for developers on Virgin's site, but couldn't find a thing.

I have checked the site with Google's Safe Browsing checker and Qualys' SSL Labs and both came out clean.

What the employee sees:

[image: Screenshot of the message the employee receives when visiting the website]

Comment: “*Don’t think this page should be blocked? Let us know.*” seems like a promising course of action in this scenario, no?

Comment: @esqew I'd like to know why it was flagged. Clicking 'Let us know' just sends the user to a page that says "Thanks for your feedback" blah blah blah.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start by seeing what your site report looks like using a tool like [Blocked.org.uk](https://www.blocked.org.uk/), which will give you a rough idea on if it's a single ISP in the UK that's filtering your site, or the entire gamut. For a single one, you may be able to get an exemption. If your site is blocked by a majority of ISPs, it may be that there is a court order or similar compelling UK ISPs to filter your site for one reason or another (unlikely, but possible).

Next, Virgin's FAQs state you can try to get in touch with someone knowledgable on the subject by posting in their [Help forum](https://community.virginmedia.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/CommunityHubForums); search "whitelist" for a few samples of folks with similar issues to yours to get an idea on how to get a helpful response.

Finally, you may have to acknowledge an uphill battle in answering the "why" - it's a fact that these companies make money (directly or otherwise) by providing a service in which they use some form of proprietary data collection and/or heuristic analysis to determine what should be filtered versus what should be allowed to be passed through. Revealing the "secret sauce" of this filtering to answer your "why" is probably not at all beneficial to them in any way. As such you may find the effort of chasing this answer down quite futile (speaking anecdotally from my own experience with similar issues: it is).